# React functional components with hooks - getting response from function written in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Need help in getting response from a function written inside reducer function

functional component

```
import {
  getAssets,
} from '../../reducers';

    const myFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const onLinkClick = () => {
        dispatch(getAssets());
      }
    }
    return (
    <div>
    <mainContent />
    </div>
    )
    }
```

In my reducer

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ASSETS_LIST: {
      return {
        ...state,
        successToast: true,
        isLoading: false,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    }
}

    export const listsDispactcher = () => dispatch => {
      dispatch({ type: SHOW_LOADER });
      performGet(ENDPOINT URL)
        .then(response => {
          debugger;
          const payload = response.data;
          dispatch({
            type: ASSETS_LIST,
            payload: {
              ...payload,
              data: payload.results,
            },
          });
          dispatch({ type: HIDE_LOADER });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch({ type: GET_ASSETS_ERROR, payload: err });
          );
        });
    };
```

when i click the link ,am getting my api called in function in reducer and its getting response in newtwork tab in developer console , but how to get the response  (that is successToast,data,isLoading )in my functional component  and to pass the same to child components ?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to change the structure of your project. Place all your network calls in a file and call them from your component. It is better for readability and understandability

```
import {
  getAssets,
} from './actions';

    const myFunctionalComponent = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

      const onLinkClick = async () => {
       const data = await dispatch(getAssets());
      }
    }
    return (
    <div>
    <mainContent />
    </div>
    )
    }
```

In ./actions.js

```
const getAssets =()=>async dispatch =>{
 const res = await axios.get();
 dispatch(setYourReduxState(res.data));
 return res.data;
}
```

Now your component will get the data of network call. and Your redux state also will get update

Answer (score 0):

For functional components, to access state stored centrally in redux you need to use `useSelector` hook from `react-redux`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
  return <div>{counter}</div>
}
```

Official doc:
https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector-examples

Also found this working example for you to refer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8l0sv